# Increased fontsize of ttk::treeview leads to overlapping rows

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

If I change the fontsize of a treeview (that is already created) from e.g. 8 to 16 the rows overlap each other. I made some attempts to change the padding but I had no success. Other widgets change automatically their size in the right way if I change the font size, but not the ttk::treeview widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option ***-rowheight***, however :

> ... The -rowheight value is not corrected by the tk scaling value or by the configured font size and must always be set ...

More about styling this widget: [ttk::treeview manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M84)

Saludos!,